# Modbus receiving same message as sent

Tags: atmega, rs485, modbus

I am having a problem when communicating with a Modbus slave.

I have made a circuit with the translator shown in the picture.   `UART2_RXD` and `UART2_TXD` is connected to the UART2 pins on a ATmega2560, and `485-EN` is connected to a digital pin.

When I sent a message via Modbus RTU I can see that the slave receives the message, but the message I read is the same I sent, even though it should not be.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

[image]

---

**EDIT**

On the B pin I read this:
[image]

Which makes me think that there is a response, but the voltage level is too low. Also the RXD pin just has a quick spike and then goes down to zero. So do I maybe have to pull it up?

Comment: I don't know how you are observing the response. You should detail your setup used to make your observations. Also, what diagnostic steps have you taken?

Comment: How is it wired up? PCB? Breadboard? Perhaps check to ensure the `!RE` pin is connected correctly as shown in the schematic.

Comment: If you just send some test characters like "abcde" or "01234" without the modbus wrapper, do you receive the same characters you sent?

Comment: I have two setups going on. On one side I have my own print which sends the modbus message through the SP485 as shown in the picture. On the other side I have a Joy it 485 to TTL converter connected to at Arduino mega2560 that are reading the response. @periblepsis

I think there is an response from the Slave, but the voltage lvl is to low as seen in the edit.

Comment: What happens if there is no Modbus slave and you send a test string? Do you receive again the same message?

Comment: _"Which makes me think that there is a response, but the voltage level is too low."_ What makes you think that the voltage level is too low? A binary `1` is specified as \$V_A - V_B < -200 mV\$ and a `0` as \$V_A - V_B > +200 mV\$.

Comment: It looks like the transmitter does not turn off tx enable directly after transmission and so there is a bus collision with the response, which looks similar, but not identical to the data sent.

Comment: If you have a 2 (or more) channel scope, measure the 485-EN signal at the same time as you're sending & receiving data and show us the result.